# General method to calculate the new movement vector (dx,dy) when the object turns clockwise or counter-clockwise on a 2D plane

Tags: vector

I am writing a program to play street soccer board game the ball moves in a 2D plane (represented as a two dimensional array). The ball at coords (x,y) can move forward, left or right. The direction in which ball is currently moving is represented by (dx,dy). Each iteration after the ball is kicked, the new position of the ball would be (x+dx,y+dy). e.g. Suppose it is moving towards south east. Then (dx,dy) would be (+1,+1).

But tell me is there a general method to calculate the new (dx,dy) when the ball 'decides' to turn left or right (clockwise or counterclockwise by 45 degree)?

i.e, if (dx,dy) = (+1,+1) , then when the ball turns clockwise, the new (dx,dy) would be (0,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help. Consider you have vector (x, y) and you want to rotate it to angle *theta*. To do that, you have to multiply your vector considered as 2x1 matrix, on rotation matrix using this formula:

[image]

[image]

So, assuming `X` axis is directed to the right and `Y` axis is directed upwards, for clockwise 45 degrees turn you have to put there `cos(-pi / 4)` and `sin(-pi / 4)`. For counterclockwise you'll have `cos(pi / 4)` and `sin(pi / 4)` respectively:

[image]

More information: [Matrix rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29), [Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this formula before but I wasnt considering conversion to radian, thats why it gave error. But is it pi/2 or pi/4

Comment: but even in that case i am not getting the expected value. suppose (dx,dy) is (1,1),ie heading SE , then turn counter clockwise means theta  = 45 degrees. I am expecting the value to be (1,0) ie heading East. But i get a fractional value there. in fact the new (dx,dy) = (0,1.414)

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan Using the formula you'll get [0, 1.414] which is the correct result. Explanation: a circle with center in (0, 0) and (1, 1) belongs to it has a sqrt(2) radius which is approximately 1.414. Now, the point (0, 1.414) is obviously lays on y axis and belongs to the same circle. The angle between (1, 1) and (0, sqrt(2)) vectors is exactly 45 degrees or pi/4 radians. I have added a picture to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I rounded off the value to get the expected and the algorithm is working as expected now. Thanks.